# Ubuntu `GLIBC_2.33' not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have following issue when I start neovim with a file that is of type python:

```
    Error detected while processing FileType Autocommands for "*":
E5108: Error executing lua Failed to load parser: uv_dlopen: /snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (requ
ired by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
```

I am on following operating system:

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 21.10 Release: 21.10
> Codename: impish

Also when I run the following command I get following which says GLIBC is installed:

```
ldd --version ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.34-0ubuntu3) 2.34 Copyright (C) 2021
Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source
for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. Written by Roland
McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

How can I fix this error or resolve this issue.
I have searched as much as I can and cannot find a resolution for this issue.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Of course you have glibc (libc6) installed. GLIBC *is* your OS (together with the kernel.) ...... Missing `/snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`, version 2.33 looks like an internal "snap" issue.

Comment: How do I resolve this issue, at the snap level. I cannot find any information on this that has helped me so far.

Comment: If the error is caused by neovim snap : `sudo snap remove --purge neovim` . ...... And suggest : `sudo apt install neovim` . I.e. neovim is available from the **universe** repo  https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/neovim → "How do I enable the Universe repository?" https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository

Comment: The ubuntu universe repo has 0.4 neovim, I need to run at least 0.5 neovim which is only available via snap.

Comment: `neovim_0.5.1-1~ubuntu21.10.1~ppa`  https://launchpad.net/~neovim-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/stable .... (update 2021-11-01) ..... When installed, you can run `dpkg -s neovim` to check status.